# preg_replace or preg_match and how can i define it right

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

This is my string:

```
$string =  "format,surcharge,amount,1,card,basicprice 3,50  F010F020,0%,3,50 ,,,";
```

and i want to have an array which should look like this:

```
array(
    0 => "format",
    1 => "surcharge",
    2 => "amount",
    3 => "1",
    4 => "card",
    5 => "basicprice",
    6 => "3,50",          //<-- tricky part, i complete don't get how i can solve this
    7 => "card",
    8 => "F010",          //<-- tricky part, i complete don't get how i can solve this   
    9 => "F020",          //<-- tricky part, i complete don't get how i can solve this
    10 => "3,50",
);
```

so my tries look like this:

```
$string =  "Format,Aufpreis,Anzahl,1,Card,Basispreis 3,50  F010F020,0%,3,50 ,,,,,,";
$regEx = '/,/';
$replace = ' ';
$perfectArray = preg_replace('/,/', $replace, $string2);
var_dump($perfectArray);
```

or like this

```
$array = str_split($string);

$from = array(",", '"');
$to = array(" ", " ");

    foreach ($array as $value)
    {
        $value = str_replace($from, $to, $string);
    }
    var_dump($value);
```

someone know how i can solve this? especially the "tricky part" (i put a comment in the code)

would be very nice if someone can answer :)

Comment: What determines that F010 is an item?  Could it be G999 or ä9A90? You have to define this in your question. And with what logic you want *"card"* to appear ***after*** *"3,50"* in the array?

Comment: You can't really solve this kind of problem with a replacement (even with a lot of tests). The best way, if it is possible, is to know what is supposed to contain each fields and to describe the whole line in a pattern for `preg_match` with capture groups. (the main idea is to describe the format of each field)

Comment: You can try if `preg_split` with [regex like this](https://regex101.com/r/yJ5cI4/1) would cover your input. [Here's a demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/517809)

Comment: It seems that the string is part of some csv is that so? if yes, are you sure that the data is like `,basicprice 3,50  F010F020,` ? isn't it within  a quote of itself like `,"basicprice 3,50  F010F020",`. Asking this because if a field in a csv contains a comma within itself then it is usually within quotes.

Comment: so the F010 always has 3 numbers after the letter, so the letter F and 3 numbers. 
card after 3,50 is only in this example, sorry. I just want to now how i can erase every "," but not if its a price or change the "," to a "." if its a price. 

Where i can find how to build capture groups with patterns?
Thank you for answering!!

Comment: jup it a csv, and the raw csv looks like this: F501,120%,"3,50 €","1,10 €","1,10 €","1,06 €","0,97 €","0,90 €","0,84 €","0,81 €","0,77 €","0,75 €","0,75 €","0,70 €","0,64 €","0,64 €",

for example

Comment: @bobblebubble Whoa! Learnt something today, great example, post it as an answer please.

Comment: @codeHeart Thanks, great it was useful :) The question seems to have changed. OP seems to parse a CSV file where input looks different. So I just leave as comment. Your's appropriate answer.

Comment: sorry that my question was wrong, so preg_split with regex i can't use with a csv to get my array ?

Comment: @aikn, if the preg_split with regex does what you need for all the kind of data that you might have then go ahead use it. I was mentioning use of some csv functions as that will make your life easier in terms of the "," that occurs between the fields(I understand that the , is a decimal, as it happens in some parts of Europe)

Comment: thank you, what would u suggest with this type of csv?
F251,43%,"3,50 €","0,50 €","0,50 €",,"0,50 €","0,50 €","0,50 €","0,49 €","0,49 €",,"0,47 €",,"0,47 €",,"0,46 €","0,46 €","0,44 €","0,44 €","0,44 €",,"0,43 €",,"0,43 €","0,43 €",,,"0,41 €",,,"0,40 €","0,40 €",,"0,39 €","0,39 €",,"0,37 €","0,37 €","0,36 €","0,36 €","0,36 €","0,36 €","0,36 €",,,,,,,,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you mentioned in comments that you have raw data in CSV format, the use of regular expression is not the best solution.

Instead split the data into an array with PHP's CSV functions, like [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php):

```php
$csv = 'F251,43%,"3,50 €","0,50 €","0,50 €",,"0,50 €","0,50 €","0,50 €","0,49 €",
        "0,49 €",,"0,47 €",,"0,47 €",,"0,46 €","0,46 €","0,44 €","0,44 €","0,44 €",,
        "0,43 €",,"0,43 €","0,43 €",,,"0,41 €",,,"0,40 €","0,40 €",,"0,39 €",
        "0,39 €",,"0,37 €","0,37 €","0,36 €","0,36 €","0,36 €","0,36 €","0,36 €"';

$data = str_getcsv($csv);

var_export ($data);
```

Output:

```php
array (
  0 => 'F251',
  1 => '43%',
  2 => '3,50 €',
  3 => '0,50 €',
  4 => '0,50 €',
  5 => '',
  6 => '0,50 €',
  7 => '0,50 €',
  8 => '0,50 €',
  9 => '0,49 €',
  10 => '0,49 €',
  11 => '',
  12 => '0,47 €',
  13 => '',
  14 => '0,47 €',
  15 => '',
  16 => '0,46 €',
  17 => '0,46 €',
  18 => '0,44 €',
  19 => '0,44 €',
  20 => '0,44 €',
  21 => '',
  22 => '0,43 €',
  23 => '',
  24 => '0,43 €',
  25 => '0,43 €',
  26 => '',
  27 => '',
  28 => '0,41 €',
  29 => '',
  30 => '',
  31 => '0,40 €',
  32 => '0,40 €',
  33 => '',
  34 => '0,39 €',
  35 => '0,39 €',
  36 => '',
  37 => '0,37 €',
  38 => '0,37 €',
  39 => '0,36 €',
  40 => '0,36 €',
  41 => '0,36 €',
  42 => '0,36 €',
  43 => '0,36 €',
)
```

If you would like to get rid of the `€` and `%` signs, and/or use the decimal point for numbers (to allow further calculations in PHP), then you could do this:

```php
$data = array_map(function ($v) { 
    // get rid of `€` or `%` at the end of values:
    $v = preg_replace('/( €|%)$/', '', $v);
    // if you want to replace the decimal comma to point for further calculations:
    $num = str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $v));
    return is_numeric($num) ? $num : $v;
}, $data);

var_export ($data);
```

Which outputs:

```php
array (
  0 => 'F251',
  1 => '43',
  2 => '3.50',
  3 => '0.50',
  4 => '0.50',
  5 => '',
  6 => '0.50',
  7 => '0.50',
  8 => '0.50',
  9 => '0.49',
  10 => '0.49',
  11 => '',
  12 => '0.47',
  13 => '',
  14 => '0.47',
  15 => '',
  16 => '0.46',
  17 => '0.46',
  18 => '0.44',
  19 => '0.44',
  20 => '0.44',
  21 => '',
  22 => '0.43',
  23 => '',
  24 => '0.43',
  25 => '0.43',
  26 => '',
  27 => '',
  28 => '0.41',
  29 => '',
  30 => '',
  31 => '0.40',
  32 => '0.40',
  33 => '',
  34 => '0.39',
  35 => '0.39',
  36 => '',
  37 => '0.37',
  38 => '0.37',
  39 => '0.36',
  40 => '0.36',
  41 => '0.36',
  42 => '0.36',
  43 => '0.36',
)
```

### Original answer based on regular expressions

You could do this with a regular expression, but it depends on what your rules are for splitting other strings. This regular expression assumes the string will always have the same number of items in the same order, and concerning the `F010` and `F020` it assumes that these always each occupy exactly 4 characters and are always present:

```php
$string = "format,surcharge,amount,1,card,basicprice 3,50  F010F020,0%,3,50 ,,,";

preg_match("/(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)\s+(.*?)\s+(.{4})(.{4}),(.*?),(\d+,\d\d)\s/",
    $string, $matches);

var_export ($matches);
```

This outputs:

```php
array (
  0 => 'format,surcharge,amount,1,card,basicprice 3,50  F010F020,0%,3,50 ',
  1 => 'format',
  2 => 'surcharge',
  3 => 'amount',
  4 => '1',
  5 => 'card',
  6 => 'basicprice',
  7 => '3,50',
  8 => 'F010',
  9 => 'F020',
  10 => '0%',
  11 => '3,50',
)
```

Comment: sorry i think i did something wrong in my question, but thanks for your answer now i know a bit better how regular expression are working.

so i get a csv which looks like this (but muuuuuch longer):
€","0,82 €"
F081,20%,"3,50 €","3,00 €","2,40 €"

and thank you of course :)

Comment: I updated my answer, using the new info that you have CSV data at the source. It is much better to deal with CSV directly than to use regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in your comments, if this is coming from csv try using

`fgetcsv` function.

You can directly work on these values.

Have a look at it here http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php, the example explains pretty well